# SPF records issue

Tags: domain-name-system, email, email-server, spf

I have an SPF record set up for my domain eg:

```
v=spf1 a mx include:mydomain.co.uk ?all
```

However, I now have to add an SPF record for a web based invoicing system which wants me to add the following to my SPF record:

```
v=spf1 mx ptr include:_spf.bidsketch.com ~all
```

If I place the two as above, into the same SPF record it shows up on mxtoolbox.com as being malformed.

So my question is how do I use the second/bidsketch record?

Do I need seperate SPF records on the same domain for this?

Or, is there a way to combine the two inside one record?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those are SPF records, not MX records.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That is not a MX record, it's a [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) record. Usually you would use a TXT record to store SPF information since most DNS servers haven't implemented the SPF RR Type yet.

Your existing SPF record should probably just be updated to reflect the requirements in the invoicing system:

```
v=spf1 a mx ptr include:mydomain.co.uk include:_spf.bidsketch.com ~all
```

If the domain for which you are implementing SPF *is* mydomain.co.uk, you should remove `include:mydomain.co.uk` from the record, otherwise, you create a recursive loop, effectively preventing the `include:_spf.bidsketch.com ~all` part from being interpreted, since RFC compliant SPF parser should stop processing a record after a maximum of 10 additional MX or PTR lookups ([IETF RFC 4408](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4408.txt) §10.1 "Processing Limits")

Comment: thanks for the loop tip!